# Is there a motivation for writing $AR(p)$ as $MA(\infty)$? Or writing a $MA(q)$ as $AR(\infty)$?

Tags: time-series

I know that it is interesting to play with different representations. However, to work with a $AR(p)$ ($MA(q)$) where $p<<\infty$ ($q<<\infty$) makes much more sense than working with a stochastic process with infinity order. What is the motivation to do that? Is there any practical motivation?

Answer (score 1):

Hi: It's not really necessary to go back to $\infty$ to get all the weights because the weights get small quickly. Since they do, they can be used to generating variance estimates of forecasts. There may be other uses also but I am unaware of them. See below for details.

https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/book/export/html/682